# How to find XML attribute within a range of values

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I'm trying to find `XML` elements that have attributes within a range of values.

I can select an XML element that has an EXACT attribute value, ie: l="855" by using `$(xml).find("line[l=855]").text()`, but I want to be able to find that element value by giving a range, say from 850-860, so that it will find 855 and return the value for that element.

Here's a sample of what I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xml = '<par><line baseline="849" l="855" t="815" r="1042" b="848"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates" ff="Courier New" fs="9." spacing="-6" scaling="876"><charParams l="855" t="816" r="873" b="845" wordStart="true" wordFromDictionary="false" wordNormal="false" wordNumeric="true" wordIdentifier="false" wordPenalty="0" meanStrokeWidth="40" charConfidence="59" serifProbability="255">0</charParams></formatting></line></par>';
    var ocrResult = $(xml).find("line[l=855]").text();
    $("#result").append(ocrResult);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgras/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a filter for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xml = '<par><line baseline="849" l="855" t="815" r="1042" b="848"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates" ff="Courier New" fs="9." spacing="-6" scaling="876"><charParams l="855" t="816" r="873" b="845" wordStart="true" wordFromDictionary="false" wordNormal="false" wordNumeric="true" wordIdentifier="false" wordPenalty="0" meanStrokeWidth="40" charConfidence="59" serifProbability="255">0</charParams></formatting></line></par>';

    var range = [850, 860];
    var ocrResult = $(xml).find("line").filter(function(){ return parseInt($(this).attr('l')) >= range[0] && parseInt($(this).attr('l')) <= range[1] }).text();
    $("#result").append(ocrResult);
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgras/3/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I had tried filtering it but was struggling with the correct syntax.